# how to get domain from data in d3js for a scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Basically,is there a shorter way of doing the following?

```
var linearScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([d3.min(initialScaleData), d3.max(initialScaleData)]) // !
                .range([0,1]);
```

Thanks!

Orkun

Comment: You can use [d3.extent](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_extent) which will return an array with two elements the min and max.

Comment: You should post an answer...